# How to tell about vertex attributes to shaders?

Tags: iphone, opengl-es, shader, vertex

I want to switch between shader programs runtime, with a fixed VBO array.

I thik I need no more than the following functions with fixed vertex attributes index (I want 0 for position, 1 for texture coordinates)

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray
glVertexAttribPointer
glGetAttribLocation
glBindAttribLocation
```

I have wired up everything, but nothing has drawn to the FBO.
If I use vertex attribute index (in glVertexAttribPointer) that has been located from the program, then it works fine, but I cannot use it with fixed attributes index.

**Can somebody show me a brief sample code that shows me the right usage/execution order of the functions above?**

Is there any missing step?

Comment: -1: "Can somebody show me a brief sample code that shows me the right usage/execution order of the functions above?" This is a terrible thing to ask. The only way you wouldn't know what order those functions go in is if you didn't know what they *do*. So you need to ask how these functions *work*; otherwise, you're just copy-and-paste coding.

Comment: @Nicol: Things like this - http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml - are really good, but tells me nothin' about the execution order.

Comment: I really know what glBindAttribLocation do, but when it not works just because I used it after linking my program, then I have no idea where to go.

Comment: Ok, +1 for you, I've found it in the documentation. :) Posted another answer.

Answer (score 3):

The point is: glBindAttribLocation must be called before link the program.

```
glBindAttribLocation(program, ATTRIBUTE_POSITION, "position");
glBindAttribLocation(program, ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE_COORDINATES, "textureCoordinates");      
glLinkProgram(program);
```

Then you can use attribute array function with fixed indices, like:

```
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIBUTE_POSITION);
glEnableVertexAttribArray(ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE_COORDINATES);    
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIBUTE_POSITION, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, _positionStride, (void*)0);    
glVertexAttribPointer(ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE_COORDINATES, 2, GL_FLOAT, GL_FALSE, _positionStride, (void*)_textureCoordinatesOffset);
```

Where indices are just simple integers, as:

```
//Vertex attributes.
enum 
{
    ATTRIBUTE_POSITION,            //0
    ATTRIBUTE_TEXTURE_COORDINATES  //1
};
```

It works now. So I don't have to call glVertexAttribPointer before every draw call.

Comment: This helped: http://samplecodebank.blogspot.com/2011/05/glbindattriblocation-example-c-c-objc.html

Answer (score 0):

As the doc says (http://www.opengl.org/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glBindAttribLocation.xml):

> Attribute variable name-to-generic attribute index bindings for a
>   program object can be explicitly assigned at any time by calling
>   glBindAttribLocation. Attribute bindings do not go into effect until
>   glLinkProgram is called. After a program object has been linked
>   successfully, the index values for generic attributes remain fixed
>   (and their values can be queried) until the next link command occurs.
>
> Applications are not allowed to bind any of the standard OpenGL vertex
>   attributes using this command, as they are bound automatically when
>   needed. **Any attribute binding that occurs after the program object has
>   been linked will not take effect** until the next time the program
>   object is linked.